# I was wondering which programming language is this?

Tags: output

What is the output of this ?

```
>>>word = "positive"
>>>word[:2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> word = "positive"
>>> word[:2]
'po'
```